# Sharepoint Columns had no property created for search

Tags: sharepoint, office365, schemacrawler

I have created 15 columns in my Sharepoint Site Document List, and I need to be able to filter or search this list by any of them.

But when I created them, only 10 of them where crawled and a ows property create for them. The other 5 where not.

Does anyone have any idea why this would be?

It's not by the datatype, because they are mostly text and choices select, and in the 10 created there are fields with the same type.

And I am sure also the names are unique, so anyone has any ideas what could be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ows property will be created for those columns which contains data. so you need to add some data in remaining columns then reindex list then it should create in few mins.